# Can there be two primary owners on a car title while only one takes out the loan?

Tags: loans, car

I am 19 and getting ready to trade in my car and get another one. I need lower insurance on this car I am getting and my parents want to put me on their insurance. The insurance agent said that my parent will have to be the primary driver which is the primary owner. I want to take out the loan myself, but at the same time I want me and my dad both to be primary owners on the title. I am going to be paying for the loan while my dad is going to be on the title as a primary owner for the insurance. Also, this is not going to be a co-signed loan, it will be my own. I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: The two questions are independent, so this reduces to "can there be two primary owners on a car title." I'd be guessing so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Not only that, but when you went to school, did you miss learning the meaning of "primary"? You dont ask for 2 primary owners, that is called joined ownership and you seem to believe that donating half your car for your father will make your bank want to give you the loan more - why?

Comment: And despite anything the agent may have said, if insurance companies where you are are anything like those in the UK, then if in the event of an accident they determine you were "in practice" the primary driver (e.g. you drove it to work every week day, your parents only used it on an occasional weekend) then any claim is likely to be thrown out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting aside the insurance question for the moment, you need to talk to the bank about the loan, but I somehow doubt that they will agree to the terms without some kind of release from your father. The problem is that the loan is secured by the vehicle, so the bank will likely need all the owners to agree to the lien. The easiest way for them to do that would be to make everyone co-sign the loan.

Re the insurance, I am troubled by the idea that the agent suggests telling the underwriter that your father is the primary driver, even if you are the one who effectively controls the car. Your parents will likely get a multi-vehicle discount, even if you are the primary driver. I also don't understand why the primary driver and "primary" owner necessarily need be the same. My wife and I are joint owners of our vehicles, but my daughter is primary on one of them, at least when she's home from school, although she has *no* ownership interest. Incidentally, while I am an owner of the cars, I am legally blind and am not even listed as a driver on the insurance at all.